# Persistence with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, model

I have some data which I rarely have to update. Further I want that data to be very fast to access. What kind of solution do you recommend me in Zend Framework. The options I thaught are a Mysql database, some XML files, or directly writing the data in php arrays... Is there any ORM library I should use?

Comment: **How much data are we talking about?** That's crucial in knowing what to recommend.

Comment: quite little, it's like if it was a CMs and I have different types of pages, each type of page would be an Object

Comment: So. . . the data you are talking about is the different types of pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using Zend Framework, why not use `Zend_Config` and store the data as `ini`/`xml`/`json`/`yaml`.

That's how Zend already stores your application settings. And if it's really not *that* much data, just store it in `application.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you can use whatever you want in your backend but then wrap it in Zend_Cache. This way you have some control over a refresh cycle but also the data in a convenient way and fast access.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an ORM if your aiming at fast access. Use an ORM for easy developing.
The fastest solution is storing this data in a plain PHP array I guess. But it's not the best solution if you ask me.

What kind of data are we talking about? How often and when does is change?

Comment: Why wouldn't a plain array be a good idea? You can use a single file that returns a value, then simply `$data = include 'data.php'`.

Answer (score 0):

Store your data in a MySQL database but also index it using Zend_Search_Lucene.

Retrieving the data from a Lucene index is pretty fast from my experience

Answer (score 0):

My favorite option in this cases is use Zend Cache. If you want to optimize the response time even more you can use the memcached library http://memcached.org/ . That can be used with Zend_Cache with little effort.